# Can't share an ssh connection with rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync

In my `.ssh/config` file I have the following:

```
Host xxx
User yyy
HostName zzzz
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
```

This works great for multiplexing my ssh connections (i.e. login once, and share the connection with multiple sessions).

I would like to multiplex (share) my ssh connection with **rsync**, so that I can do things like

```
rsync -arv -e ssh xxx:/source target
```

and not have to login through **rsync** (I have two-factor authentication system with XXX and it would be great if I can just skip that when I use rsync).

**Update:** I learn that by default rsync would try to re-use the connection first. So I am not sure why it isn't working. Here is the verbose output of my attempt:

```
> rsync -arv -e 'ssh -v' XXX:~/file ~/temp/.
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/YYYY/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for XXX
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
Control socket connect(/home/YYY/.ssh/XXX@ZZZZ:22): Connection refused
```

Comment: This should be working.  Maybe try `-e 'ssh -v'` to see if `rsync` over `ssh` is indeed looking for the ControlMaster socket?

Comment: And yet, plain `ssh` not invoked by `rsync` works?

Comment: Ì guess the space in `Control master auto` (rather than `ControlMaster`) is not contained in the config?

Comment: @jw013, plain ssh not invoked by rsync works. yes.

Comment: Unfortunately I am out of ideas, except perhaps to add a few more `-v`'s to see if `ssh` will tell you the reason for the `Control socket connect Connection refused` line.

Comment: Have you checked whether the master process is still running after the rsync attempt?

Comment: @artistoex  Yes the master process and connection is still working.

Comment: does the socket show up in netstat (or /proc/net/unix)?

Comment: It would be nice to know why `connect(2)` fails.  Can you start the master ssh with strace and see what the call returns? (The moment rsync tries to connect to the socket something like `connect(....) = ER...` should appear in the strace log)

Comment: Sorry, `connect(2)` should of course appear in rsync's strace, but it's anyway interesting to know how the ssh process reacts.  So what returns connect() in rsync's strace and what happens on ssh's strace?

Comment: (for rsync, start strace with the -f option in order to trace the ssh child process)

Comment: What happens if instead of `XXX:~/file` you will use `XXX:file`?

Comment: @Karlson I think he's given up.

Comment: @artistoex, thanks for your help. I am working with the sys admin on this. I'll try what you suggested and update the OP accordingly.

Comment: Is your home directory on NFS? I'm not sure how FIFOs behave there. Maybe trying setting ControlPath to /tmp/$USER.ssh/%r@%h:%p (with the appropriate permissions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried this exact thing and it worked for me.

**NOTE:** I should also include that prior to running the commands below I ran this command, which sets up the user account on the remote host for use with my local user account's ssh credentials.

```
ssh-copy-id root@skinner
```

My setup is as follows:

#### `$HOME/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa

Host skinner mulder byers
    User root
```

#### contents of `$HOME/.ssh/`:

```
$ ls -dl ~/.ssh
drwx------ 2 saml saml 4096 May 23 03:18 /home/saml/.ssh

$ ls -l ~/.ssh
total 16
-rw------- 1 saml saml 204 May 23 03:17 config
-rw------- 1 saml saml 736 Jan 10  2011 id_dsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml 612 Jan 10  2011 id_dsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml 401 May 23 03:17 known_hosts
```

#### Now ssh to host skinner:

[image: ss of initial ssh]

#### contents of `$HOME/.ssh/`:

```
$ ls -l ~/.ssh
total 16
-rw------- 1 saml saml 204 May 23 03:17 config
-rw------- 1 saml saml 736 Jan 10  2011 id_dsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml 612 Jan 10  2011 id_dsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml 401 May 23 03:17 known_hosts
srw------- 1 saml saml   0 May 23 03:25 master-root@skinner:22
```

#### send `somefile.txt` to remote host:

```
$ rsync -arv -e ssh somefile.txt skinner:~
sending incremental file list
somefile.txt

sent 106 bytes  received 31 bytes  91.33 bytes/sec
total size is 13  speedup is 0.09
```

#### pull `somefile.txt` from remote host:

```
$ rsync -arv -e ssh skinner:~/somefile.txt somefile-remote.txt
receiving incremental file list
somefile.txt

sent 30 bytes  received 100 bytes  260.00 bytes/sec
total size is 13  speedup is 0.10
```

#### results of above rsync commands:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 13 May 23 03:19 somefile-remote.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 13 May 23 03:19 somefile.txt
```

#### send `somefile.txt` to remote host (-v):

```
$ rsync -arv -e 'ssh -v' somefile.txt skinner:~
OpenSSH_5.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e-fips 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/saml/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Applying options for skinner
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 5
sending incremental file list
somefile.txt
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 5

sent 106 bytes  received 31 bytes  274.00 bytes/sec
total size is 13  speedup is 0.09
```

#### send `somefile.txt` to remote host (-vv):

```
$ rsync -arv -e 'ssh -vv' somefile.txt skinner:~
OpenSSH_5.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e-fips 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/saml/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Applying options for skinner
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 5
sending incremental file list
somefile.txt
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 5
debug2: Received exit status from master 0

sent 106 bytes  received 31 bytes  274.00 bytes/sec
total size is 13  speedup is 0.09
```

Answer (score 1):

Might it be a problem related to the usage of your ssh key? On the remote server, check your key in the `authorized_keys` file and verify that you did not limited the allowed usage with the `command=` parameter. More information on the file format is available at http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html .