# bash: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, io-redirection

Create a ssh key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa –P ""
```

Moving the key to authorized key:

```
$ cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys

bash: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Same question, why you need to add the key to your own host?

Comment: @Braiam I've done this when my home directory was on network drive. This allowed me to ssh to any machine that mounted this drive. So I wasn't sshing to my own host.

Answer (score 15):

```
bash: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
```

An element of the path `/home/user/.ssh/` does not exist; the shell (`bash`) checks the redirection (`>>`) before it executes the command (`cat`).  If `/home/user` does exist and you try this:

```
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/test_this
```

You'll now get:

```
cat: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

Since that file can't be in that place, if `/home/user/.ssh/` did not exist to start with.

You're following some instructions having possibly skipped some bits.  To create the directory:

```
mkdir $HOME/.ssh
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh
```

However, `id_rsa.pub` won't be there.  It will be wherever you ran the `ssh-keygen` command in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you are logged in as the user that you want to create the ssh key for first (or be prepared to modify the paths in the command to the correct home directory).

Then just create the directory:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
```

Create the file using the `cat` command you have listed above. Then don't forget to set the permissions correctly:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You might want to make sure that the .ssh directory has appropriate permissions as well.

Comment: As your last comment implies, yes I find you need to `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 6):

If possible I always encourage people to use the commandline tool `ssh-copy-id`.

```
$ ssh-copy-id -h
Usage: /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id [-i [identity_file]] [user@]machine
```

If you just want to copy your default SSH public key to a remote server, you simply run the following command:

```
$ ssh-copy-id user@remoteserver
```

I show an actual full example of how to use this tool in this Q&A titled: [Can't share an ssh connection with rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/cant-share-an-ssh-connection-with-rsync/76784#76784).

Answer (score 0):

This can also fail if, when creating the key with `ssh-keygen`, you give it a filename. I entered some name `my-ssh-file-name`, and it wrote the key to `/Users/MyUserName` instead of the `.ssh` folder. If you leave the filename blank, it will write to `.ssh` as expected.

Comment: or of course you can specify to write the custom key to .ssh folder directly: `-f ~/.ssh/custom-key-name`